# gem install returns FloatDomainError Infinity or NaN

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, rubygems

On Ubuntu 10.10, I cannot install any gems!

```
$ sudo gem install rails
ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    too many connection resets (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Ok, so the proxy is in the way :-

```
$ sudo gem install -p http://username:password@the.proxy.com:8080 rails 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (FloatDomainError)
    NaN
Fetching: activesupport-3.0.3.gem(1)
```

*1) This is where it returned the cursor to, not a new line?! It does this on every call below as well.*

Get the same with another gem :-

```
$ sudo gem install --http-proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080 twitter
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (FloatDomainError)
    NaN
Fetching: hashie-0.4.0.gem
```

*I have tried -p as well!*

But my`http_proxy`env var is setup correctly :-

```
$ env | grep http
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy.com:8080
```

As stuff like this works :-

```
$ gem list -r rails

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

rails (3.0.3)
rails-action-args (0.1.1)
rails-admin (0.0.0)
rails-app-installer (0.2.0)
rails-app-spec (0.3.2)
...
```

*And all the`apt-get`&`curl`commands go straight though without problems.*

Versions :-

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]

$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
$ whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/bin/ruby /usr/lib/ruby /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz

$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ree-1.8.7-2010.02 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p136 [ i386 ]

$ rvm -v
rvm 1.2.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

$ gem -v
1.4.2

$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem
$ whereis gem
gem: /usr/bin/gem /usr/bin/gem1.8 /usr/share/man/man1/gem.1.gz
```

Any help/ideas?

Comment: I get this myself, but it's JRuby 1.6.0.RC1 on Windows XP, so I'm not sure it's Ubuntu related, but it could very well be proxy related (as i have a proxy, too.)

What kind of proxy does your company use?  I think mine uses something like McAffee Web Gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to use the Ubuntu package of Ruby or RubyGems.  Ideally, remove those packages with `apt-get uninstall` and start from scratch with [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) (Ruby Version Manager).

When using `rvm`, it's usually best to install gems locally (a.k.a., do not use `sudo` and system-wide installs).

A good write up on all of this is Ryan Bigg's blog post [Ubuntu, Ruby, RVM, Rails, and You](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you).

Comment: I dont know who marked you down, but +1 from me as its good advice, and along the same lines as others offline have said. "Install from source" tents to be the answer for dev boxes.

Comment: Ok, how about myself?  I have this exact same issue: JRuby on Windows XP.  I'm sure your advice was/is well-intentioned, but it isn't useful, at least to me.  It sounds like handwaving the problem because you believe RVM is superior.  This is like having a .dll issue in Windows and get an answer saying switch to OS X.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue behind a company gateway.  It went fine on the WiFi at the hotel.  My guess is it is the virus scan on the company gateway.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in RubyGems 1.4.2.  See this [GemCutter Help page](http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/461-gem-install-throws-floatdomainerror-when-behind-proxy-jruby-160rc1-w-rubygems-142) for more details.

If you want to try out the latest build from trunk that fixes this, feel free to checkout Rubygems from source and install manually:

```
$> git clone https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.git
$> cd rubygems
$> ruby setup.rb
$> gem env  // You should see RubyGems 1.5.0 or something similar if you've installed it
$> gem update // or `gem install` or whatever you want to test out
```